# Как отдалить экран по макс на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, как сделать так что при заходе на сайт с мобильного устройства сайт отдалялся по max, верстка не адаптивная.

Answer (score 1):

добавить в `head`

```
<meta name="viewport" content='width=1200' />
```

1200 - ширина контентной области

[Viewport Meta Tag](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design)